# html span class causing links to center incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to make my own website for a game I'm making. I've been trying to have the links all centered in one div class and another div beside it horizontally showing some info for each tab. But to put the text in a horizontal line I had to use the span class which has caused a few problems with the centering of 1 of the links.Any idea's how I can center this link correctly?

Link to site: https://mywebsite-rowanharley.c9users.io/main.php

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site - Home</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css">-->
    <style type="text/css">
        #sidebarlink{
            display: block;
            color: white;
            width: 200px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:link {
            width:200px;
            background-color: black;
            color:white;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:visited{
            width:200px;
            background-color: black;
            color:white;
        }
        #sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:hover{
            width:200px;
            background-color: #454545;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:active{
            width:200px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #sidebar{
            width: 200px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #playerFriendsDiv{
            /*display: inline;*/
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #showYourInfoDiv{
            /*display: inline;*/
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #logoutDiv{
            /*display: inline-block;*/
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: 200px;
        }
        html{
            height: 100%;
        }
        body{
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showYourInfoDiv">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="playerFriendsDiv">
        test2
    </div>
    <div id="logoutDiv">
        test3
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" style="text-align: center">
        <div id="sidebarlinkdiv">
            <a onclick="showyourinfo()" id="sidebarlink">Player info</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebarlinkdiv">
            <a onclick="showfriends()" id="sidebarlink">Friends</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebarlinkdiv">
            <a onclick="showlogout()" id="sidebarlink">Logout</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("showYourInfoDiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("playerFriendsDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.display = "none";
        function showyourinfo(){
            document.getElementById("showYourInfoDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("playerFriendsDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
        function showfriends(){
            document.getElementById("showYourInfoDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("playerFriendsDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
        function showlogout(){
            document.getElementById("showYourInfoDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("playerFriendsDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have also tryed surrounding the links in center tags

Comment: Why don't you put _style_ in different **css** file.

Comment: because I tryed that but the stylesheet doesn't do anything

Comment: May be you forgot to include the css file in HTML :P

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple same `sidebarlink` id's.

Comment: You mean how to center 'Player Info' text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center "Player info" link, just add `position: absolute` to the `#sidebar` div style.

Also, change `id="sidebarlink"` to `class="sidebarlink"` and in css `#sidebarlink` to `.sidebarlink`, because there can be only one element with given id, which should be unique.

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/90Lgck79/1/

Comment: I changed the links from ids to classes and the #sidebarlink to .sidebarlink and now the links have disappeared. If you go and highlight all the text on the page you can see there's text there and if you click on the text it changes the text beside it

Comment: You need to change all `#sidebarlink` to `.sidebarlink` in your css - check the jsfiddle link I included in my answer.

Comment: sorry found out why the text disappeared. I changed the divs from id's to classes instead of the links

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin` to set margin for you elements.

Comment: the margin only seems to move the links position. It doesn't do anything to the text

Comment: set `margin` to the text, not to the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**CSS**

```
#showYourInfoDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

#sidebarlink {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

You should do something like this **https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/73/**

**HTML**

```
 <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarlinkdiv">
        <a onclick="showyourinfo()" class="sidebarlink">Player info</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarlinkdiv">
        <a onclick="showfriends()" class="sidebarlink">Friends</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarlinkdiv">
        <a onclick="showlogout()" class="sidebarlink">Logout</a>
    </div>
 </div>


 <div id="main-content">
    <div id="showYourInfoDiv">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="playerFriendsDiv">
        test2
    </div>
    <div id="logoutDiv">
        test3
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebarlink{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:link {
    width:200px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:visited{
    width:200px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}
.sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:hover{
    width:200px;
    background-color: #454545;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebarlink/*.sidebarlink*/:active{
    width:200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And instead of `id` or `#` use `class` or `.` if you want to have multiple same ids

Comment: this is causing the span class to put itself on a new line and the page is now scrollable which didnt happen before

Comment: Remove this `style="display: block;` from `showYourInfoDiv` in your `HTML`  and add `float: left` to `id="sidebar"` in `CSS`